# How do I automatically unlock login keyring when logging into Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: login, 20.04, keyrings, gnome-keyring, hyper-v

When I login to my Ubuntu 20.04 Hyper-V VM [this pops up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFOK5.png). How do I automatically login without having to type my password a second time. I see I can disable the keyring password but I'm just checking if there is a more secure way to achieve this. I am sure I did this on Ubuntu 18.04 but I can't remember how.

Comment: Remove the keyring and next popup will ask for a password. Save that keyring without a password. After that it will no longer appear.

Comment: I'm asking is there any way to login to the keyring automatically without removing it entirely.

Comment: Nope. Was not possible in 18.04 either. You will need to save this keyring without a password for it to not ask for a password.

Comment: No worries, I can deal with having to enter my password twice, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

From your question and comment it seems you enter your password twice, once at login and once to unlock the keyring.

This can happen if your 'login' keyring is not the default, for example after changing your password, see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/617679/how-to-solve-the-login-keyring-did-not-get-unlocked-when-you-logged-into-your-c)

If you use the Automatic login feature in Ubuntu, you'll still get this prompt, because you didn't unlock the keyring when logging in. In that case, and I have to stress to do this only on a trusted machine in a trusted network and probably not to do this at all because of the security leak, but the only way to get rid of it then is indeed to set a blank password to the keyring. (see also [this](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/keyring-not-unlocking-4175506629/#post5410389) interesting thread)

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the "Login keyring" as the default keyring and set its password to be your login password. For example, use seahorse: `sudo apt-get install seahorse && seahorse`.

Be aware that if you activate automatic login, i.e., login without password, you will see the pop-up again, unless you set an empty password for the "Login keyring".

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Hyper-V's enhanced session, the keyring will not be unlocked by default because you are logging in via xrdp instead of the display manager.

Copying the configuration from `/etc/pam.d/gdm-fingerprint` (assuming gdm) to `/etc/pam.d/xrdp-sesman` will fix this. Make sure to put the lines in the same sections as the original.

My config as an example:

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth required pam_env.so readenv=1
auth required pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
@include common-auth
auth    optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so
@include common-account
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad] pam_selinux.so close
session required        pam_limits.so
@include common-session
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad] pam_selinux.so open
session optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
session required        pam_env.so readenv=1
session required        pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
@include common-password
```

Answer (score -1):

to remove this annoying xrdp keyring password dialog in mint 20.3 (may be similar in ubuntu 20.4) go to: `cat /etc/pam.d/lightdm`:

find module includes:

```
@include common-auth
-auth    optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so
...
@include common-session
-session optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
...
```

add the above `-auth` and `-session` parameters to the same includes in `/etc/pam.d/xrdp-sesman`:

```
@include common-auth
-auth    optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so
```

```
@include common-session
-session optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
```

this should work